# Django: How to render model data into HTML template?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to display user info from my model named `Listing` that's in the django admin into my HTML template named `myaccount.html` and I have not had any success.

What am I doing wrong with my current code?

Any help is gladly appreciated. Cheers.

## user_profile/models

```
from django.contrib import auth
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.conf import settings

class Listing (models.Model):

    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created =  models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    rank = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        user_profile = Listing.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])

post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=CustomUser)
```

## user_profile/views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.http import HttpResponseNotFound
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.conf import settings
from .forms import HomeForm
from .models import Listing
from users.models import CustomUser

def change_view(request):
    form = HomeForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None,)
    user_profile = Listing.objects.all
    user = request.user

    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            listing_instance = form.save(commit=False)  
            listing_instance.user = user 
            listing_instance.save() 
            return redirect("myaccount")

    context = {
        'form': form, 'user_profile': user_profile 
    }

    return render(request, "myaccount.html", context)
```

**HTML**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} 
{% load static %} 
<p>{{ Listing.name }}</p>
<p>{{ Listing.address }}</p>
{% block content %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: your list of `Listing` objects is called `user_profile` in your context. So `{% for profile in user_profile %} {{ profile.name }} {{ profile.address }} {% endfor %}` will show you all the `Listings`. Note one mistake: `user_profile = Listing.objects.all()` with brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list of `Listing` objects is called `user_profile` in your context. So:

```
{% for profile in user_profile %} 
    {{ profile.name }} 
    {{ profile.address }} 
{% endfor %}
```

will show you all the `Listings`.

Note one mistake: It should be `user_profile = Listing.objects.all()` with brackets. And I would advise you to use plural `user_profiles` since you're fetching multiple. Makes it easier to understand your code.

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you my friend. I made those adjustments and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Change your html to

```
<p>{{ form.name }}</p>
<p>{{ form.address }}</p>
```

Comment: When I do that I render the actual form inputs. I need to render the data from the model that's stored in the django admin into the html. Sorry if I don't know but I'm new to Django. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oh @dirkgroten explain well. Sorry I misunderstand your question. Happy coding with django!